# WPF Localization in the easiest way

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, resources

I'm localizing my WPF app. Is there any way to refer to the keys like this:

```
Strings.log_in
```

Where Strings is the default resource file. And log_in is a custom key and with value?

So Strings.resx is the default resource file (uk english), and I also created a Strings.en-US.resx file.

So my aim is the following:
I have this two resource files. And if I switch in my program to US english, then the Strings.log_in would mean US english.

How can I do that?

So far I wrote the following code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Settings.Default.Language);
ResourceManager RM = new ResourceManager("MyProgram.Resources.String", typeof(App).Assembly);
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your current solution? You can access it like you described with "Strings.log_in" and it is returned in the language of the current thread.

Comment: OMG it really does. :D THANKS A LOT!

Comment: Additionally: creation of the ResourceManager is not needed.